# $x^2+px+q=0$ where $p+q=2017$, find integers only $x_1$ and $x_2$

Tags: quadratics

Using a program I found one pair only x1=-1 x2=-1008, maybe there are more, but I need a step by step mathematical solution.

Comment: What is $(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Number-theory problems that involve the current year are often contest problems, so many readers will refrain from giving too complete replies, lest they become complicit in cheating.

Comment: I had this problem on my contest today, but my brain did not have the strength to solve it. :( But I got my answer now.

Comment: This one is super easy. It ultimately boils down to factoring $2017.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Vieta: $x_1+x_2=-p$ and $x_1x_2=q$ so:

$x_1x_2-x_1-x_2+1=p+q+1=2018$

$(x_1-1)(x_2-1)=2018$

So you can get $x_1$ and $x_2$ by factoring $2018$.

The prime factoring of $2018$ is $2\cdot 1009$

So $2018=(\pm 1)\cdot(\pm2018)=(\pm 2)\cdot (\pm 1009)$

Which gives you $8$ solutions:

$(-1,-2017),(-2017,-1),(2,2019),(2019,2),(-1,-1008),(-1008,-1),(3,1010),(1010,3)$

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant is $$p^2-4q=p^2-4(2017-p)=(p+2)^2-4\cdot2018$$ which needs to be perfect square.

If $(p+2)^2-4\cdot2018=r^2\iff(p+2+r)(p+2-r)=4\cdot2018$

Now as $(p+2+r)\pm(p+2-r)$ are even and the Right Hand Side, both $(p+2+r),(p+2-r)$ have to  be even

$$\dfrac{p+2+r}2\cdot\dfrac{p+2-r}2=2018=2\cdot1009$$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}{\bf Hint}\quad  x^2\! + px +q-1 \,&=\ \ {-}1\\[.1em]
-\ (\, q + p\, &=\ \ \  2017\,)\\[.1em]
\hline
\Rightarrow\quad { x^2\! + px - p-1} &=\, -2018\\[.1em]
{\rm i.e.}\quad    (x\! -\! 1)\ (x\! +\! p\!+\!1) &=\, -2018
\end{align}$